# Basemap creates large values when transforming lat/lon to x/y

Tags: python, spyder, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using Spyder IDE and I'm trying to plot some locations using basemap. When I plug in some lat/lon coordinates, I get exceedingly large xy values (Which will not appear on the plot). I have consulted various sample codes and cannot figure out what is wrong...

For example:
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

```
m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=35,urcrnrlat=40,\
        llcrnrlon=-125,urcrnrlon=-120,resolution='c')


x,y = m(37.5,-122.5)
print(x,y)
```

yields:

```
(18069167.07126069, 1e+30)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have your longitude and latitude the wrong way round. The x axis would be equivalent to longitude.

```
x,y = m(-122.5, 37.5)
```